# CSS-less vue component fails when copied from vue2/vuetify project to vue2/tailwind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have written a very simple, learning "hello world" type component, in the vue 2/typescript 4 project at:

https://github.com/sldev2/vr-vtsv-timeline

This project was made with vue ui. I've added @vue/composition-api 1.0.3 and vuetify 2.4.0

The component is called CompositionApiEg.vue. It doesn't use any explicit vuetify styles. When you browse to http://localhost:8080/,  It displays 3 names, and allows you to increase "capacity" by clicking the button with text "Increase Capacity". (The button border does not show. I know not why; I assume I need a vuetify button style) There are no runtime errors in the browser.

The CompositionApiEg.vue file is [here](https://github.com/sldev2/vr-vtsv-timeline/blob/master/src/components/CompositionApiEg.vue).

I've tried transplanting this component into another vue2/typescript 4 project also made with vue ui, with the composition-api added, but that has tailwind instead of vuetify. The component was not modified in any way. In particular, no tailwind styles were added.

This project is at: https://github.com/sldev2/v23tstw

Now, however, this component is  throwing a bunch of runtime errors, such as:

## warning eg:

vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "spacesLeft" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

## error eg:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:1897 TypeError: _vm.increaseCapacity is not a function
    at click (CompositionApiEg.vue?c6d9:27)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:1863)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:2188)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:6961)
```

Why does the exact same, very simple component succeed in one vue2 project, but not in another?

Comment: Technically it should work (from the first look).
I'd have to see the whol integration into the other project to judge correctly

Comment: 1 thing i noticed is that i the first project you are using different `@vue/composition-api` versions. `1.0.3` and `1.1.1` but I don't think that this should cause these many issues

Comment: I didn't mention it, but had tried downgrading @vue/composition-api from 1.1.1 to 1.0.3 ; same errors

Comment: I tried your component in your other project and it works. Maybe there is something wrong with the composition-api module. I suggest removing `node_modules` and reinstalling (`rm -rf node_modules && pnpm install`).

Comment: @Ali Momen Sani

Would you please verify that you simply cloned https://github.com/sldev2/v23tstw, then ran: pnpm install? If not, what did you do?

Comment: @SperoLarres Yes, and added `CompositionApiEg.vue` and replaced `Home.vue` with it in router.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get to this, sooner. I just tried re-cloning  github.com/sldev2/v23tstw, then simply replaced the code in Home.vue with the code from CompositionApiEg.vue. It still doesn't render in the browser, correctly. And it still shows errors in Chrome Dev Tools, including
========================================
vue.runtime.esm.js?d04a:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "spacesLeft" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 
========================================

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pnpm. I'll try with npm.

Comment: Using npm instead of pnpm still leads to errors. Perhaps I should note that I ran 'npm run lint --fix' to fix linting errors in the CompositionApiEg